# Writing a binary tree in C with lacking knowledge

Tags: c, binary-tree

Since I am only starting my A level, I don't know about nodes or anything and subsequently aren't meant to use them. I ended up getting really confused and coded this, so far it runs about half the code but seems to get stuck in the while loop and the else statement within it. Once again I am sure it is pretty terrible coding but I am very much a beginner.
Any advice on how to fix it or a better way would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int numbers[9][3]= {
        {67,34,78,45,12,19,37,92,72},
        {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
        {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}
    };
int i=0,x=0,y=0,z=0;
//x is for looping 
//z acts as a boolean for whether or not the number has been put in the correct position
//y acts as a temporary position
printf("started ");
for( x = 1; x < 9; x++ )
{
    printf("does the for loop ");
    y=0;
    if((numbers[x][0])<=(numbers[y][0]))
    {
        while(z==0) 
        {
            printf("starts the while loop ");
            if(numbers[y][1]=='-1')
            {
                printf("inside if in while loop ");
                numbers[y][1]=x;
                z=1;
            }   
            else;
            {
                printf("inside else in while loop ");   
                y=numbers[y][1];
            }
        }
    }
    else;
    {
        while(z==0) 
        {
            if(numbers[y][2]=='-1')
            {
                numbers[y][2]=x;
                z=1;
            }   
            else;
            {
                y=numbers[y][2];
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("out of while loop ");
for( i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
{
printf("%d: %d,%d,%d\n"),(i+1),(numbers[i][0]),(numbers[i][1]),(numbers[i][2]);
}

printf("done ");

return 0;


}
```

Comment: `'-1'` is almost certainly wrong. When comparing integers, use an integer. `if(numbers[y][1] == -1)` Can you explain what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: regarding; `if(numbers[y][1]=='-1')`   This is comparing an `int` with two characters.  However, '-1' is two characters and cannot have a multi char literal with '...'

Comment: regarding: `else;
                {
                    printf("inside else in while loop ");   
                    y=numbers[y][1];
                }`  The semicolon ';' after the `else` ends the else code block  Strongly suggest removing that semicolon

Comment: regarding: `printf("%d: %d,%d,%d\n"),(i+1),(numbers[i][0]),(numbers[i][1]),(numbers[i][2]);`  the parens `()` around the values to be printed is an error.  Suggest: `printf( "%d: %d,%d,%d\n", i+1, numbers[i][0], numbers[i][1], numbers[i][2] );`  Also, notice how much more readable it is with appropriate horizontal spacing.  Also, the trailing paren `)` in `"%d: %d,%d,%d\n"),` ends the statement.

Answer (score 3):

I am certain that you have a typing error. You added a semicolon after the else, this causes the while loop to run every time. Also, you compared integers with a char, as stated in the comment by retired ninja.
I think this code will run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int numbers[9][3]= {
        {67,34,78,45,12,19,37,92,72},
        {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
        {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}
    };
    int i = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    //x is for looping 
    //z acts as a boolean for whether or not the number has been put in the correct position
    //y acts as a temporary position
    printf("started ");
    for( x = 1; x < 9; x++ )
    {
        printf("does the for loop ");
        y = 0;
        if((numbers[x][0]) <= (numbers[y][0]))
        {
            while(z == 0) 
            {
                printf("starts the while loop ");
                if(numbers[y][1] == -1)
                {
                    printf("inside if in while loop ");
                    numbers[y][1] = x;
                    z = 1;
                }   
                else
                {
                    printf("inside else in while loop ");   
                    y=numbers[y][1];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while(z == 0) 
            {
                if(numbers[y][2] == -1)
                {
                    numbers[y][2] = x;
                    z = 1;
                }   
                else
                {
                    y = numbers[y][2];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("out of while loop ");
    for( i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
    {
        printf("%d: %d,%d,%d\n"),(i + 1),(numbers[i][0]),(numbers[i][1]),(numbers[i][2]);
    }

    printf("done ");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but still had the same looping issue.

Comment: @Retired Ninja I realise now I had cast them as char but either way it still failed. Also the purpose of checking if it was -1 was to see if it already had a pointer. It was basically what my teacher told me to do

Comment: did you include the last part where you print your solution

Comment: You need that to print your solution, I just included the chunk of code that has you mistake. I'll edit it with the last part.

Comment: still looping at the else statement in the while loop like 6 times then stopping. Thanks for the help though.